# How to get a list from a linq to Entity Framework query using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, list

I thought getting data from an SQL table in VB.Net would be easy, especially with Linq, but I just can't get it to work. I'm using a code-first model.

I have no idea why the following code gives me an error "Public member 'ToList' on type 'DbQuery(Of Company)' not found."

I can't even to a "For Each" over the query.

```
        Dim lCompany1 = From proc In model1.Companies _
                    Where proc.Website = website _
                    Select proc

        Dim products As IEnumerable(Of Company) = lCompany1.ToList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following:

```
    Dim con As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Model1").ConnectionString
    Dim db As New DataContext(con)
    Dim a As Table(Of Catagory2)
    a = db.GetTable(Of Catagory2)()
    Dim dt As List(Of Catagory2) = a.AsQueryable.Where(Function(p) p.Town.Contains("something")).ToList()
```

And I used the following model:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Linq.Mapping

<Table(name:="Category")> _
Public Class Catagory2
Private _Id As Integer
Private _Town As String
Private _Category As String
Private _Done As String
Private _State As String
Private _URL As String

<Column(IsPrimaryKey:=True, IsDbGenerated:=True)> _
Public Property Id() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Id
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _Id = value
    End Set
End Property

<Column(CanBeNull:=True)> _
Public Property Town() As String
    Get
        Return _Town
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Town = value
    End Set
End Property

<Column(CanBeNull:=True)> _
Public Property Category() As String
    Get
        Return _Category
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Category = value
    End Set
End Property

<Column(CanBeNull:=True)> _
Public Property State() As String
    Get
        Return _State
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _State = value
    End Set
End Property

<Column(CanBeNull:=True)> _
Public Property Done() As String
    Get
        Return _Done
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Done = value
    End Set
End Property

<Column(CanBeNull:=True)> _
Public Property URL() As String
    Get
        Return _URL
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _URL = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

It didn't work with the model created by Entity Framework's create code-first model.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Dim lCompany1 = (From proc In model1.Companies 
                 Where proc.Website = website).ToList()
```

Comment: I want to update the record, but when I do something like "lCompany1.Website = website"  it gives me an error " Public member 'Website' on type 'DbQuery(Of Company) not found.", when using "Dim lCompany1 = (From proc In model1.Companies  Where proc.Website = website)"

Comment: Using "Dim lCompany = lCompany1.First" gives me the same error

Comment: I got it to work by using "                 For Each company As Company In lCompany1 ,
                    company.Website = website ,
                Next"   But I still wonder why "First" wouldn't work

Comment: I'm not sure why your getting a `DbQuery(Of Company)` as a result.

Comment: That answer you gave me doesn't work either, it just puts in the data I key in but doesn't return anything

Comment: To change the records you have to change them in code and then call `SaveChanges()` on the model.